# Adding a dependency that is internal to a company to pom.xml

Tags: spring-boot, maven

How do use import an internal, a dependency internally accessible to a compayny, in maven springoot project?
I have tried downloading the jar of the dependency and adding it to the project's external libraries but still doesnt work,.

Comment: Your best bet is to host your own repository for company-internal artifacts and then configure that using a `<repository>` element. Everything else is just short-term workarounds that don't allow you to make full use of Maven. Also I'm pretty sure that the fact that this is a Spring Boot based project doesn't matter here. As long as you use Maven to build your project, the process is the same.

Comment: Setup your `settings.xml` file to consume everything from your repository manager...